# How to expand this macro properly?

Tags: c++, c, macros

When I define this macro:

```
#define SQR(x) x*x
```

Let's say this expression:

```
SQR(a+b)
```

This expression will be replaced by the macro and looks like:

```
a+b*a+b
```

But, if I put a `++` operator before the expression:

```
++SQR(a+b)
```

What the expression looks like now? Is this `++` placed befor every part of SQR paramete?  Like this:

```
++a+b*++a+b
```

Here I give a simple program:

```
#define SQR(x) x*x
int a, k = 3;
a = SQR(k+1) // 7
a = ++SQR(k+1) //9
```

Comment: When you say `++SQR(3+1)`, how do you know it's 9? `++3` shouldn't compile.

Comment: @chris You are right. I edited my question.

Comment: Now I forget whether `++k * k` is undefined or not. Remember macros substitute text. Yours then becomes `++k+1*k+1`.

Comment: `++k*k` smells like UB. Even if it isn't, I'd definitely avoid it.

Comment: `++k*k` is undefined behaviour.  Don't go there.

Comment: Actually I think it is, even in a more complex case. `operator+(++k, operator*(1, k))` has an  unspecified order of argument evaluation.

Comment: ++SQR(x) seems like a bad idea, as its behavior depends on exactly what the SQR macro ends up putting next to it. But as nneonneo's answer says, the ++ will not be expanded, macros are very simple (and dangerous) and they do not pay attention to their surroundings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When defining macros, you basically *always* want to put the macro parameters in parens to prevent the kind of weird behaviour in your first example, and put the result in parens so it can be safely used without side-effects. Using

```
#define SQR(x) ((x)*(x))
```

makes `SQR(a+b)` expand to `((a+b)*(a+b))` which would be mathematically correct (unlike `a+b*a+b`, which is equal to ab+a+b).

Putting things before or after a macro won't enter the macro. So `++SQR(x)` becomes `++x*x` in your example.

Note the following:

```
int a=3, b=1;
SQR(a+b) // ==> a+b*a+b = 3+1*3+1 = 7
++SQR(a+b) // ==> ++a+b*a+b ==> 4 + 1*4 + 1 = 9
           // since preincrement will affect the value of a before it is read.
```

You're seeing the `++SQR(a+b)` appear to increment by 2 since the preincrement kicks in before `a` i read either time, i.e. `a` increments, then is used twice and so the result is 2 higher than expected.

*NOTE* As @JonathanLeffler points out, the latter call invokes undefined behaviour; the evaluation is not guaranteed to happen left-to-right. It might produce different results on different compilers/OSes, and thus should never be relied on.

Comment: I know a proper macro should be in parens, but for this question, how can I get 9 when I expand into a expresson like this:  `++k+1*k+1` when `k = 3`?

Comment: Mild challenge question: can you think of a circumstance where it would be necessary to add parentheses around the macro parameter names in an example like this: `#define macro(a, b) some_func(1, a, b, __FILE__, __LINE__)`?  _Hint:_ I can't, but I'm mortal.

Comment: @stevenYANG: Any way the compiler likes; it can give you any answer (-1, 37, 496) and it is still a valid answer because you've invoked undefined behaviour.

Comment: @stevenYANG, Although UB, notice that if `++k` is evaluated first, it's `4 + 1*4 + 1`, which equals 9. That's probably where it came from.

Comment: @stevenYANG Learn the operator precedence to figure out how to evaluate expressions. In this case, however, `++k+1*k+1` invokes undefined behavior because the value being modified (`k` in `++k`) is used more than once (also in `1*k`) in the expression, so all bets are off.

Comment: @nneonneo Yeah~I forget the preincremet will change the value before the operation. In this expression, preincrement will be executed first, because its pecendence?

Comment: Note that `++a+a*b+b` could perfectly well yield 8 if the compiler evaluates `a*b` before it evaluates `++a`.  But since the expression has UB, it could evaluate to _any_ value and the compiler would be correct.  It isn't even required that `a` ends up holding the value 4, AFAIK (though it is pretty improbable that it will hold any other value).

Comment: @stevenYANG No, the precedence doesn't say what is evaluated first, only how the implicit parentheses are placed.

Comment: @stevenYANG as Jonathan says `++k+1*k+1` makes your program an invalid program. The standard says that this kind of programs are simply not-valid and what they do is undefined. Undefined means that anything is always correct as the program itself is wrong. You could get 9, you could get 0, you could get a string, you could get your disk formatted or anything. As most programmers say, _the correct result is that you get ghosts coming out of your nose_.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I couldn't either. But I'm curious to know if such scenario exists.

Comment: @chris right. I just retranslated in english the way we say it over here. It did not feel completely right, but it just did not come to my mind the english idiomatic. Not that it makes a big difference for the OP.

Comment: Actually, won't work. `e.c:3:8: error: macro "macro" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given`

Comment: But, the similar `macro({a, b})` will...now, what are you going to use these newfound powers of evil for?

Answer (score 1):

For C++ the right way to define this macro is to not use a macro, but instead use:

```
template<typename T> static T SQR( T a ) { return a*a; }
```

This will get right some horrible cases that the macro gets wrong:

For example:

```
SQR(++a);
```

with the function form `++a` will be evaluated once. In the macro form you get undefined behaviour as you modify and read a value multiple times between sequence points (at least for C++)

Comment: If you're really going for it, `template<typename T> static auto SQR(T a) -> decltype(a * a) {return a * a;}`, in the rare case that a T times a T is not a T.

Answer (score 0):

A macro definition just replaces the code,hence it is generally preferable to put into parenthesis otherwise the code may replaced in a way you don't want.

Hence if you define it as :

```
#define SQR(x) ((x)*(x))
```

then

> ++SQR(a+b) = ++((a+b)*(a+b))

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `++SQR(a+b)` should be expanded as `++a+b*a+b`.
So, if a == 3 and b == 1 you will get the answer `9` if the compiler evaluates it from left to right.

But your statement `++SQR(3+1)` is not correct because it will be expanded as `++3+1*3+1` where `++3` is invalid.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the answer will be 9.  The behaviour is undefined; any answer is acceptable.  C does not automatically evaluate left-to-right or right-to-left.

Answer (score 0):

In your preprocessor it evaluates to ++a+b*a+b. The right way is put brackets around each term and around the whole thing, like:

```
#define SQR(x)  ((x)*(x))
```

Comment: You really need another set of parentheses too; otherwise, you get surprising results if you evaluate `1.0/SQR(2.0)`.