# I have defined a macro sqr(x) which takes one argument and return x*x. When I call the macro with sqr(5+4), it return 29. Can someone please explain?

Tags: c, macros

Here is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define sqr(x) x*x
void main()
{
    printf("\n%d",sqr(9));
    printf("\n%d",sqr(5+4));
}
```

The output is : 
81
29

Comment: Basic rule of defining macro, wrap the arguments in `(` brackets `)`.

Comment: The macro expands to `5+4*5+4` which is `29`.

Comment: `5+4*5+4` is `5+(4*5)+4` is `5+20+4` is `29`. You need `#define sqr(x) ((x) * (x))`

Comment: Prefer ALLCAPS for macros, and get into the habit of "saying" `int main(void) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70078674/i-define-macro-as-define-sqrtxxx-and-int-x-16-sqrt4-but-x-is-16-why

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833569/define-sqrx-xx-unexpected-answer

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662815/define-squarex-xx

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683670/c-preprocessor-instructions-sqr-funktion

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165356/what-is-the-difference-between-xx-and-xx-in-c

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73548321/can-somebody-explain-the-outcome-of-macro-preprocessor-in-c-squarex-xx-why

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822341/incorrect-answer-from-define-sqrx-xx

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506058/how-to-expand-this-macro-properly

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719150/square-of-a-number-being-defined-using-define

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820421/macro-argument-with-different-results

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351051/problem-with-macros

Comment: Oh my gosh. Everyone's having problems with their SQR macro...

Answer (score 0):

Having SQR as a macro will never be correct. Make it a function. In C++, the function can be `constexpr`, in C it should probably be `inline`.

The following code goes through all iterations of attempting to fix the macro. Note how only the function gives the correct result and no macro does.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
// Original (very incorrect)
#define SQR(x) x*x

// First correction (still incorrect)
#define SQR2(x) (x)*(x)

// second correction (still incorrect)
#define SQR3(x) ((x)*(x))

// correct
int square(int x){ return x*x; }

int main()
{
    int x1 = SQR(5);
    printf("5²=%d (correct so far)\n", x1);

    int x2 = SQR(1+1);
    printf("(1+1)²=%d (problem: operator precedence)\n", x2);
    
    int x3 = SQR2(1+1);
    printf("(1+1)²= %d (first correction)\n",x3);

    printf("sizeof (int) = %d\n", sizeof(int));
    int x4 = sizeof SQR2(1+1);
    printf("sizeof (1+1)²= %d (problem: operator precedence)\n", x4);
    
    int x5 = sizeof SQR3(1+1);
    printf("sizeof (1+1)²=%d (second correction)\n", x5);

    
    int i=2;
    int x6 = SQR3(i++);
    printf("(i++)²=%d (expected: 4, problem: undefined behavior)\n", x6);

    i=2;
    int x7 = SQR3(++i);
    printf("(++i)²=%d (expected: 9, problem: undefined behavior)\n", x7);

    i=2;
    int x8 = square(i++);
    printf("(i++)²=%d (expected: 4)\n",x8);

    i=2;
    int x9 = square(++i);
    printf("(++i)²=%d (expected: 9)\n",x9);
}
```

[Try it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ejTcnxMsn)