# What is the difference between x*x and (x)*(x) in C?

Tags: c, macros

This programm returns a=25, but if I define the sqr(x) as (x*x) it returns a=11. Why does this happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define sqr(x) ((x)*(x))
main (){
    int a,b=3;
    
    a=sqr(b+2);
    printf("a=%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Becasue `b + 2 * b + 2` is not `(b + 2) * (b + 2)`

Comment: In C macros are expanded during preprocessing, so instead of calling `sqr` like you would generally call a function, the definition is first expanded to `((x)*(x))` and `x` is replaced with `(b + 2)` in this instance.

Comment: There *has* to be a dup for this, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is in the way the macro is expanded.

With the extra parenthesis, the preprocessor expands the expression `sqr(b+2)` to this:

`((b+2)*(b+2))`

Which the compiler then interprets as:

```c
a = ((3+2)*(3+2))
  = (5*5)
  = 25
```

Without the extra parenthesis, the preprocessor expands the expression `sqr(b+2)` to this:

`(b+2*b+2)`

Which the compiler interprets as:

```c
a = (3+2*3+2)
  = (3+(2*3)+2)
  = (3+6+2)
  = 11
```

The `*` (multiplication) operator has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the `+` (addition) operator.

Answer (score 0):

If the macro is defined like

```
#define sqr(x) ( x * x )
```

when in this macro extension

```
sqr(b+2);
```

after substituting `x` for `b + 2` you will have

```
b + 2 * b + 2
```

It is not the same as

```
( b + 2 ) * ( b + 2 )
```

that you would have if the macro was defined like

```
#define sqr(x) ( ( x ) * ( x ) )
```