# Macros not producing required result

Tags: c, macros

I am new to C (coming previously from Python). I am confused over this part of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define square(x) x*x
int main()
{
    int x = 36/square(6);
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why macro square(x) is not producing output 1 and why is it printing 36? Can you shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the macro in parentheses, like this:

```
#define square(x) (x*x)
```

The way you've written it, `36/square(6)` expands to `36/6*6`, which is evaluated as `(36/6)*6`, or 36.

With parentheses, it will correctly be evaluated as `36/(6*6)`, or 1.

Comment: This macro is still wrong. `square(1+1)` will be 3 instead of 4. And possibly, `int i=1; int result=square(i++);` is undefined behavior (at least in C++). Just use a function, not a macro at all. `constexpr` if you can (C++).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76719135/480982