# I define macro as #define SQRT(X)X*X and int x=16/SQRT(4) ,but x is 16 ,why?

Tags: c, macros

```
    #include <stdio.h>    
    #define SQRT(X)X*X
    int main(){
     int x=16/SQRT(4);
     printf("%d",x);
    
     return 0;
    }
```

this output is 16 why? firstly i defined macro and then try do calculation

Comment: @AlexF, what `SQRT(2+2)` would be?

Comment: may I ask why the word "square" is abbreviated as "SQRT"? There is no "t" there.

Comment: @tstanisl - Always keep your enemies guessing. Up is down, left is right, and squaring is SQRT.

Comment: You need to study how to write function-like macros in your beginner-level C book before using them. This here is a super-common FAQ that any half-decent book will address.

Comment: SQRT usually does something right opposite `sqrt(4) = 2`, `sqrt(9) = 3` This name is **taken**!!. Do not use it unless you want confuse the code readers.#

Comment: Why do you want to use macro for that?

Answer (score 4):

Currently `int x=16/SQRT(4);` will expand to `int x=16/4*4;` which is clearly 16. Use brackets to ensure the macro expansion is as intended:

```
#define SQRT(X) ((X)*(X))
```

Aside: `SQRT` is an odd name for the macro as that usually means "square root". `SQR` or `SQUARE` would be a more appropriate name.

Comment: Yes I understood Thanks

Comment: I don't know C exactly, but in C++ this may still produce incorrect results (undefined behavior) if you use it like this:
`int x = 2;
int result = SQRT(x++);` Use a `constexpr` function instead and no macro at all.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/76719135/480982